# nginx not serving wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi

I'm doing this [tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) to setup my django application to run on `nginx`. Everything works except for `nginx` serving the `wsgi` it is supposedly listening for on port 8001.

I run `uwsgi` with `uwsgi --socket :8001 -b 32000 --wsgi-file test.py` - this can be served as http on port 8000 fine as earlier in the tutorial.

Below is my .conf file, but some things I am confused about is what should be in the `/etc/nginx/sites-*/` folders. Currently I have a symlink of the below .conf file in the `sites-enabled` directory.

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 127.0.0.1; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias _;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias ~/path/i/changed/to/app/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     ~/path/i/changed/to/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the logs from nginx and uwsgi say? Did you restart Nginx, btw?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by launching nginx with a specified config file, i.e. `nginx -c /path/to/mycoolsite_nginx.conf`. Still not sure what the `sites-*` folders are actually for...